# How can I create an instance of a type in a template function? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, default

I need a template function which assigns a default value to the argument passed

```
template <class T> inline T GetDefault()
{
    return ???? # default value
}
```

`T` cand be `bool`, `int`, `double` and `string`.

Thank you.

Comment: All instances of `GetDefault<T>` should just be replaced with `T()`; the function serves no purpose but to add code and confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default value (even with basic types) should be default "constructor" :

```
template <class T> inline void SetDefault( T& value )
{
    value = T();
}
```

For example, int-based types will be 0 by default (because explicitely initialized).

This will obviously not work with types with no default value, like objects of class that don't have a default constructor.

Comment: Why did you change the function declaration?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `return T();`

Note that this can also be used to give a parameter of template type a default value :

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T &t, const T &tWithDefaultValue = T())
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: @Klaim: The word you are looking for is "brevity" ;-)

Comment: Right, not native-english, sorry. ^^; Looks like the french word but I thought it was a "false friend".

Answer (score 5):

```
template <class T> inline T GetDefault() 
{ 
    return T();
}
```